# Multiple if else condition in react native

Tags: react-native

I have to display different icon based on a condition

> `Icon name={route.routeName=='Profile'?"home":"calendar"}`

I have four items in route.routeName . It works fine if i have only 2 items in route.routeName.  Can anyone help me to figure out how to set up multiple if-else condition in scenarios like this?

Answer (score -1):

Can do something like this:

```
{
 (route.routeName=='Profile') &&
 <Icon name='Profile/>
}
{
 (route.routeName=='home') &&
 <Icon name='Home'/>
}
{
 (route.routeName=='calendar') &&
 <Icon name='calendar'/>
}
```

Comment: perhaps a more compact version of your code { (route.routeName === 'Profile' && <Icon name='Profile/>)
  || (route.routeName === 'home' && <Icon name='Home'/> ) }

Comment: Using single `&&` is already clean to look at. I don't typically use `||` since it will be considered at the same line, not good for multiple conditions
maybe try deconstruction above `const { routeName } = route`

Comment: this answer is not valid